# CUDA nvprof number of floating point ops

Tags: cuda, profiling

I am curious to why the number of flops reported by the profiler is not equal to the sum of ADDs, MULs and FMAs?

```
Invocations                     Metric Name              Metric Description         Min         Max         Avg
Device "GeForce GTX 780 Ti (0)"
    Kernel: mul_mm(double const *, double*, int, int, int)
         30                        flops_dp                   FLOPS(Double)   159500000   159500000   159500000
         30                    flops_dp_add               FLOPS(Double Add)           0           0           0
         30                    flops_dp_mul               FLOPS(Double Mul)    17000000    17000000    17000000
         30                    flops_dp_fma               FLOPS(Double FMA)    71250000    71250000    71250000
```

I get `159500000 - 17000000 - 71250000 = 71250000`. Is this just accidental or are FMAs counted twice?

Answer (score 3):

The flops metrics count the number of operations not instructions executed. FMA and DFMA count as 2 operations. The profiler's definition of flops is inconsistent given it counts a FMA as 2 for one counter and 1 for another.

Peak FLOPs is calculated as GpuClockFrequency * CudaCoresPerSm * SmCount * 2 ops/FMA.

Comment: Thank you Greg. When you say it is inconsistent do you mean that the profiler reports inconsistent results? Am I correct to say that `flops_dp = flops_dp_add + flops_dp_mul + 2 * flops_dp_fma`? Also, is peak floating-point performance for CUDA GPUs quoted in terms of operations or instructions?